# NodeJS - Process out of memory for 100+ concurrent connections

Tags: mysql, node.js, concurrency, socket.io, out-of-memory

I am working on an IoT application where the clients send bio-potential information every 2 seconds to the server. The client sends a CSV file containing 400 rows of data every 2 seconds. I have a Socket.IO websocket server running on my server which captures this information from each client. Once this information is captured, the server must push these 400 records into a mysql database every 2 seconds for each client. While this worked perfectly well as long as the number of clients were small, as the number of clients grew the server started throwing the "Process out of memory exception."

Following is the exception received :

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
   98522 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.1 (1457.9) -> 1397.1 (1457.9) MB, 1522.7 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  100059 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.1 (1457.9) -> 1397.0 (1457.9) MB, 1536.9 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  101579 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.0 (1457.9) -> 1397.0 (1457.9) MB, 1519.9 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
  103097 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.0 (1457.9) -> 1397.0 (1457.9) MB, 1517.9 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x35cc9bbb4629 <JS Object>
    2: format [/xxxx/node_modules/mysql/node_modules/sqlstring/lib/SqlString.js:~73] [pc=0x6991adfdf6f] (this=0x349863632099 <an Object with map 0x209c9c99fbd1>,sql=0x2dca2e10a4c9 <String[84]: Insert into rent_66 (sample_id,sample_time, data_1,data_2,data_3) values ? >,values=0x356da3596b9 <JS Array[1]>,stringifyObjects=0x35cc9bb04251 <false>,timeZone=0x303eff...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted
```

Following is the code for my server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mysql = require('mysql');

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '<host>',
    user: '<user>',
    password: '<password>',
    database: '<db>',
    debug: false,
});

conn.connect();

io.on('connection', function (socket){
   console.log('connection');
var finalArray = []
   socket.on('data_to_save', function (from, msg) {
   var str_arr = msg.split("\n");
   var id = str_arr[1];
   var timestamp = str_arr[0];
   var data = str_arr.splice(2);
   finalArray = [];
   var dataPoint = [];
   data.forEach(function(value){
        dataPoint = value.split(",");
        if(dataPoint[0]!=''){
                finalArray.push([dataPoint[0],1,dataPoint[1],dataPoint[2],dataPoint[3]]);
                finalArray.push([dataPoint[0],1,dataPoint[4],dataPoint[5],dataPoint[5]]);
        }
   });
   var sql = "Insert into rent_"+id+" (sample_id,sample_time, channel_1,channel_2,channel_3) values ? ";
   var query = conn.query (sql, [finalArray],function(err,result){
       if(err)
           console.log(err);
        else
         console.log(result);
   });

   conn.commit();
   console.log('MSG  from ' +  str_arr[1] + ' ' + str_arr[0] );

});

});
http.listen(9000, function () {
  console.log('listening on *:9000');
});
```

I was able to get the server to handle 100 concurrent connections after which I started receiving process out of memory exceptions. Before the database inserts were introduced, the server would simply store the csv as a file on disk. With that set up the server was able to handle 1200+ concurrent connections.

Based on the information available on the internet, looks like the database insert query (which is asynchronous) holds the 400 row array in memory till the insert goes through. As a result, as the number of clients grow, the memory foot-print of the server increases, thereby running out of memory eventually.

I did go through many suggestions made on the internet regarding `--max_old_space_size`, I am not sure that this is a long term solution. Also, I am not sure on what basis I should decide the value that should be mentioned here.

Also, I have gone through suggestions which talk about async utility module. However, inserting data serially may introduce a huge delay between the time when client inserts data and when the server saves this data to the database.

I have gone in circles around this problem many times. Is there a way the server can handle information coming from 1000+ concurrent clients and save that data into Mysql database with minimum latency. I have hit a road block here, and any help in this direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how this got into your code, but the quotes in this are not legal Javascript: `socket.on(‘data_to_save’, ...)`.

Comment: I am not an expert of MySQL, either a good solution could arise from better configuration of it, or I would suggest going to a more lightweight DB system, MongoDB for example.

Comment: I'd first comment out your database code and see if you can handle just the incoming messages.  If you can handle that just fine, then the problem is with your DB code (perhaps a memory or resource leak in it).

Comment: Where are you?  Two people tried to engage to help and you aren't here to correspond.  This isn't like other drive-by forums.  stackoverflow works best for you if you hang around for 30 mins or so after posting to engage the people that try to help.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for pointing out about the quotes in JavaScript. I am not sure and will look into it. Also, as I pointed out in my question, originally the server saved data as CSV files on disk, with which I was able to achieve far higher concurrency. Also, I do appreciate the help received on stack overflow. It is definitely not a drive-by forum for me and I appreciate the contributions and help offered by many experienced professionals. Based on my previous experiences, I had not received an almost immediate response hence did think of checking stackoverflow immediately.

Comment: @Pac0, thank you so much for your suggestion. As of now we are constrained with using MySQL DB. We are debugging the code for memory leak issues.

Comment: Unless you write perfect questions that garner complete answers without any interaction with others, you WILL need to be around to engage with people that are trying to help you.  If you don't get any response in the first 30 minutes, then you've probably not made your question very approachable or you have ventured into a corner of the programming world that most people don't know about (this is rare).

Comment: A good question that is clear and to-the-point will very likely get at least some sort of response in the first 30 minutes.  If you aren't around then, you lose your best opportunity to engage with the first people that try to help you.  And, your question may also get downvotes or close votes, further discouraging others from spending any time on it.  And, if your question is off-the-mark or unclear, then those first 30 minutes are your best opportunity to clarify and fix the question so people are more likely to know how to help you.

Comment: Anyway, I think your first step in diagnosing this is (as I pointed out above) is to figure out whether this is a request volume handling issue or a database scalability issue because you go completely different directions to fix it depending upon which is the main contributor to the problem.  We can't figure that our for you because it involves experimentation and measurement.  So, I'm waiting for your report on that.  Once you know which is the bottleneck, we could help with suggestions for dealing with the issue.

Comment: @jfriend00, thank you. Will make sure I follow this next time.

Comment: @jfriend00, to narrow down the problem, I used --max-old-space-size=8192 option with my node server. This helped in increasing my concurrency from 100 users to 200 users. This leads me to believe that the problem lies with the nodejs rather than the database.

Comment: That  doesn't tell you whether it is simultaneous request handling or database logic that is using too much memory.  That's what I wanted to know.  All you proved is that something is using memory so when you increased the memory ceiling things got better.  That doesn't tell you anything about WHAT is using the large amount of memory.  I think that's what you need to know.  This is a problem that needs a "scientific method" applied to the problem solving to narrow down the main cause.

Comment: @jfriend00, any pointers on how to test request handling vs database logic? When I run the code that saved data as CSV files to the disk, it is able to handle far higher concurrent users.

Comment: Run request handling all by itself with no saving of results at all.  See how high you can go.  If you can go really high with that (like thousands), then you will have your  answer. Your database code is using too much memory and you will have to learn a lot more  about how to optimize that or how to increase its scalability.

Comment: If you prove the problem is database activity, then the first thing I'd do is to use [connection pooling](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) since that's really easy to implement and might help.  Beyond this, you'll have to do some database diagnostics to figure out why it's using so much memory.  My best guess would be that some database resource is not getting released properly, but I don't know your database well to know where to look there.

Comment: @jfriend00, your suggestion of using connection pooling proved to be helpful. Also, I was using a relatively small database instance which was limiting the number of concurrent connections. As a result, as the number of inserts from the concurrent connections grew, the CPU utilization shot up to 100% thereby increasing the query time multi-fold. Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll summarize my comments since they sent you on the correct path to address your issue.

First, you have to establish whether the issue is caused by your database or not.  The simplest way to do that is to comment out the database portion and see how high you can scale.  If you get into the thousands without a memory or CPU issue, then your focus can shift to figuring out why adding the database code into the mix causes the problem.

Assuming the issues is caused by your database, then you need to start understanding how it is handling things when there are lots of active database requests.  Oftentimes, the first thing to use with a busy database is [connection pooling](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections).  This gives you three main things that can help with scale.

1. It gives you fast reuse of previously opened connections so you don't have every single operation creating its own connection and then closing it.
2. It lets you specify the max number of simultaneous database connections in the pool you want at the same time (controlling the max load you throw at the database and also probably limiting the max amount of memory it will use).  Connections beyond that limit will be queued (which is usually what you want in high load situations so you don't overwhelm the resources you have).
3. It makes it easier to see if you have a connection leak problem as rather than just leak connections until you run out of some resource, the pool will quickly be empty in testing and your server will not be able to process any more transactions (so you are much more likely to see the problem in testing).

Then, you probably also want to look at the transaction times for your database connections to see how fast they can handle any given transaction.  You know how many transactions/sec you are trying to process so you need to see if your database and the way it's configured and resourced (memory, CPU, speed of disk, etc...) is capable of keeping up with the load you want to throw at it.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the default memory(512MB) by using the command below:

> node --max-old-space-size=1024 index.js

This increases the size to 1GB. You can use this command to further increase the default memory.